# Find counter example

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Statement: ∃ A ∀ B (A = A ∪ B)

I know this statement is false, and we can solve it by taking its negation:

∀ A ∃ B (A ≠ A ∪ B) , and set B = {x}, where x ∉ A.

However, I think that setting A = B, then B = B ∪ B would make the statement true. Would it be possible to find a counter example to this?

Or would there be a way to prove this statement without taking its negation?

Comment: No: You cannot use a counterexample to disprove a statement of the form $\exists A$.

Comment: Please explain, in your own words and understanding, the difference between "finding a counter-example" and "taking its negation."

Comment: i was meaning, finding a counter example to "for all set B, B= B union B is true", since my claim is setting A = B makes the statement true. sorry i must have been unclear. @mathguy

Comment: You can't set $A=B$ in the first place; the quantifiers $\exists A\forall B$ mean that $A$ must be independent of $B$. (Also, your proof of the negation doesn't work either; how do you know that there is some $x\not\in A$?)

Comment: You can use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts, though it may not be crucial for this post.

Comment: How does specification tell you that there is an $x$ such that $x \not \in A$?  It just allows you to collect the members of $A$ that satisfy some property.  It doesn't tell you there is anything not in $A$.

Comment: @RossMillikan Take note over here I am forming a set B, which satisfy the property that its elements are not in A. I am not forming a set A. Like the Russel's paradox that there exist set x such that x∉A.

Comment: But you must appeal to the axioms to form $B$.  Specification cannot give you a $B$ that is disjoint from $A$ because everything it gives you is a subset of $A$.  Russel's paradox is from naive set theory which has unrestricted comprehension.  ZFC prevents that by using specification.  As I said in my answer, if the universe is a set the statement is true.  If it is not a set, as in ZFC, the statement is false.

Comment: @RossMillikan I understand that the statement is false if the universeis not a set. My problem here is I have difficulty convincing myself that the original statement is false when I do not negate it. For example, I have difficulty convincing myself that  for all sets, B = B ∪ B is false (here i am setting A = B, which is my "there exist an A"). Hence i needed a counter example to "for all sets, B =  B = B ∪ B".

Comment: No you don't need a counterexample to $B=B \cup B$ and you won't find one.  In your negation, given any $A$ there is some $B$ such that...  You need that for any $A$ there is some set not a subset of $A$ for that.  Foundation will give you that.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the set theory and universe you are using.  If the universe is a set, $A$ is the universe and the statement is true.  If the universe is not a set, for each $A$ you can find an $x \not \in A$ as you suggest and the statement is false.  In ZFC there is no universal set and the statement is false.

As an example, let the sets we talk about be all subsets of $\{1,2,3\}$.  Then if $A=\{1,2,3\}$ the statement is true.

Comment: assuming there is no universal set, can we prove the original statement without taking negation?

Comment: If there is no universal set you cannot prove the original statement because it is false.

Comment: is there a counter example to setting  A = B, then  B = B ∪ B ?

Comment: @Jenny: NO. The issue with your "proof" is that you need an $x$ that is not an element of $A$. The classical way to get such an $x$ (by no means obvious!) is to take $x$= the set of all subsets of $A$. To prove that this $x$ is not an element of $A$, you need to invoke the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 0):

If there exist universal set then the statement is true, $A$ is the universal set.

If there is no universal set then the statement is indeed false but you can't disprove it by counter example, because you are saying $\exists A$, this means that there is at least one! Which means that unless you showed that the statement is false for every set there is then we can't conclude anything.

The proof goes like this:

$A$ is not universal set hence $\exists x, x\notin A$, by setting $B=C+x$ where $C\subseteq A$ and $x\notin A$ we have $A\cup B=A+x\ne A$